# iCheck checkbox becomes unclickable after applying pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination, icheck

I am trying to create pagination for dynamic tables with data from the database. What I did was, I loaded first all the records and paginated the result. The pagination is working, however, the checkbox becomes unclickable.

I'm guessing it's because of how I stored all the **tr**s into an array to display it.

**HTML**

**Buttons**

```
<div class="btn-group float-right">
    <button class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-prev"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

**Table**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-mail">
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            if(!empty($mails)){
                foreach($mails as $key) {
                    $isRead = ($key['isRead'] == 0) ? "unread" : "read";
                    $isImportant = ($key['isImportant'] == 1) ? "<span class='float-left text-warning important'><i class='fa fa-star'></i></span>" : "";
        ?>
        <tr class="<?php echo $isRead; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $key['mailID']; ?>">
            <td class="check-mail">
                <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
            </td>
            <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=<?php echo $key['mailID']; ?>"><?php echo $isImportant; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo ucwords(strtolower($guiClass->e($key['name']))); ?></a></td>
            <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=<?php echo $key['mailID']; ?>"><?php echo mb_strimwidth(ucfirst($guiClass->e($key['subject'])), 0, 60, "..."); ?></a></td>
            <td class="text-right mail-date"><?php echo time_passed(date(strtotime($key['created_at']))); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }}else{ ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">No Messages</td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".i-checks").iCheck({
            checkboxClass: "icheckbox_square-green",
            radioClass: "iradio_square-green",
        });

        // Pagination
        var current_page = 1;
        var records_per_page = 10;
        var records = $(".table-mail").find("tbody").find("tr").length;
        var data = [];
        
        $(".mail-box")
        .find("table")
        .find("tbody")
        .find("tr")
        .each(function () {
            data.push($(this).prop("outerHTML"));
        });
        
        function prevPage() {
        if (current_page > 1) {
            current_page--;
            changePage(current_page);
        }
        }
        function nextPage() {
        if (current_page < numPages()) {
            current_page++;
            changePage(current_page);
        }
        }
        function numPages() {
        return Math.ceil(records / records_per_page);
        }
        
        function changePage(page) {
        var table = $(".table-mail").find("tbody");
        
        if (page < 1) page = 1;
        if (page > numPages()) page = numPages();
        
        table.html("");
        
        for (
            var i = (page - 1) * records_per_page;
            i < page * records_per_page;
            i++
        ) {
            table.append(data[i]);
        }
        }
        
        $(".btn-next").click(function () {
        nextPage();
        });
        
        $(".btn-prev").click(function () {
        prevPage();
        });
        
        changePage(1);
    });
</script>
```

[image: Interface]

**EDIT**

Based on some comments, **reinitializing iCheck** is the way to go. But it is still not working (at least in my current code).

For testing purposes, I tried hardcoding **tr**s using the code below and used this to append to the tbody, and **it worked**. I also added the reinitialization of iCheck in this test.

```
for (var i = 0; i < records; i++) {
    tr[i] =
        "<tr class='read' data-id='" +
        i +
        "'><td class='check-mail'><input type='checkbox' class='i-checks mail' autocomplete='off'></td><td class='mail-contact'><a href='mail_detail.php?id=1'>&nbsp;John Doe</a></td><td class='mail-subject'><a href='mail_detail.php?id=1'>This is a subject " +
        i +
        "</a></td><td class='text-right mail-date'>2 hours ago</td></tr>";
}
```

So, just like my first guess, I think the problem lies in how I get all the **tr**s and stored them in array called data, and displayed it back.
Any suggestions on how should I properly get all the  **tr**s?

Comment: Hello, have you tried to initialize them first? or after you populate the table you need to initialize them back because the icheck might have been destroyed.

Comment: I think it happens because the original checkboxes are destroyed during pagination and you lose all the event listeners. This is usually prevented with event delegation on the parent, but since you initialize them with a plugin, better call `$(".i-checks").iCheck()` after every pagination.

Comment: I added the reinitialization, but still not working. I guess it's because of how I get all the trs and stored them in array. Look for my **Edit**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by the guys in the comments you've to reinitialize the icheck components after the pagination, so better to add the code below at the end of the `changePage` function :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Pagination
  var current_page = 1;
  var records_per_page = 10;
  var records = $(".table-mail").find("tbody").find("tr").length;
  var data = [];

  $(".mail-box")
    .find("table")
    .find("tbody")
    .find("tr")
    .each(function() {
      data.push($(this).prop("outerHTML"));
    });

  function prevPage() {
    if (current_page > 1) {
      current_page--;
      changePage(current_page);
    }
  }

  function nextPage() {
    if (current_page < numPages()) {
      current_page++;
      changePage(current_page);
    }
  }

  function numPages() {
    return Math.ceil(records / records_per_page);
  }

  function changePage(page) {
    var table = $(".table-mail").find("tbody");

    if (page < 1) page = 1;
    if (page > numPages()) page = numPages();

    table.html("");

    for (
      var i = (page - 1) * records_per_page; i < page * records_per_page; i++
    ) {
      table.append(data[i]);
    }

    $(".i-checks").iCheck({
      checkboxClass: "icheckbox_square-green",
      radioClass: "iradio_square-green",
    });

  }

  $(".btn-next").click(function() {
    nextPage();
  });

  $(".btn-prev").click(function() {
    prevPage();
  });

  changePage(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.3/icheck.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.3/skins/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="mail-box">
  <div class="btn-group float-right">
    <button class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-prev"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
  </div>

  <table class="table table-hover table-mail">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 1</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="read" data-id="1">
        <td class="check-mail">
          <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks mail" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-contact"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=1">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id=2">PAGE 2</a></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">PAGE 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the reinitialization, but still not working. I guess it's because of how I get all the trs and stored them in array. Look for my **Edit**

Comment: Can you show us `mail-box` table structure

Comment: mail-box is just a div wrapper of the .table-mail. I have now specified the table itself.

Comment: Check the update with working example.

Comment: Thanks! Finally it is working. I noticed that initializing iCheck at the top of the script is what causing checkboxes to be unclickable. So I removed it and moved the initialization to after each pagination is the solution. Thanks a lot.